# Having a problem with package tkz-euclide, some packages doesn't work overleaf

Tags: tkz-euclide

So I'm pretty new to Latex. Few days ago I discovered a package called tkz-euclide  and it looked pretty interesting. Later on I found this pdf coursebook (http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf) and if i want to use some commands from it in overleaf (the online compiler) it says the sequence was never def'ed. In preamble I put all my casual packages (idk if some may be unnecessary). So here is little example of what causes the crash:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz} % remove this
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{etex}% remove this
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, babel, intersections, plotmarks, matrix, quotes, angles, mindmap, arrows, folding, shapes, trees, hobby, backgrounds, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\usetkzobj{all} % remove this if tkz-euclide version >3

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{----- \\ 06.04.2020}
\lhead{Zadanie}
\rfoot{Strona \thepage}

\begin{document}
\section*{----}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/1/B,1/4/C}
    \tkzClipPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDefTriangleCenter[ortho](B,C,A)
    \tkzGetPoint{H} \tkzLabelPoints[below](H) %<-----THIS LINE
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And i noticed it's the `\tkzDefTriangleCenter[ortho](B,C,A)` command.
Here is a screenshot:[image: in overlea]

Anybody knows the sulution?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: it's better to give a minimum example showing the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know 'overleaf' but I think you have a problem with the version of 'tkz-euclide'.
You need to use version 3.05 or 3.06 of 'tkz-base and tkz-euclide'.

With the last version you don't need to use `\usetkzobj{all}`

Now `\usepackage{etex}`is not necessary.
\usepackage{tikz} is not necessary because tkz-euclide loads TikZ.

After that if my code compiles, you can add several packages one by one to test the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/1/B,1/4/C}
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDefTriangleCenter[ortho](B,C,A)
    \tkzGetPoint{H} \tkzLabelPoints[below](H) %<-----THIS LINE
    \tkzDrawLines[add= 0 and 1](A,H B,H C,H)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]